# React JS - webpack script in package.json not working

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm doing Tyler Mcginess's course on react and my package.json is not loading the webpack -p properly, it's returning this error.

Failed at the react@1.0.0 production script 'webpack -p'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the react package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself

package.json.

```
{
  "name": "react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "production": "webpack -p"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.7.7",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.16.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js.

```
module.exports = {

    entry: [
        './app/index.js',
    ],

    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: "index_bundle.js"
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: "babel-loader"}
        ]
    },

    plugins: [HtmlWebpackPluginConfig]

}
```

Comment: does it work when you try to run "webpack -p" in the console without the script?

Comment: LoadersList.js:81
  r.forEach(function(r) {
    ^

TypeError: r.forEach is not a function

Comment: did you add es2015 and react presets to babelrc?

Comment: Yeah i did, still not working :-)

Comment: Why your package called `react`? :)

Comment: @BobSponge, it's just an arbitrary name, i found a solution, on mac, "." files are hidden so webpack wasn't picking up the . extension, so including a query key worked passing in an array of presets.

Comment: Thanks to @QoP for the input :-).

Comment: you are welcome @SpencerHire

Answer (score 1):

On mac, "." files are hidden so webpack wasn't picking up the . extension, so including a query key worked passing in an array of presets and deleting the .babelrc file.

```
module: {
        loaders: [
            {   
                test: /\.js$/, 
                exclude: /node_modules/, 
                loader: "babel",
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
```